# regex for multiple strings

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have two strings that I'm trying to match in a file and return just that line.

The first string will match what I'm looking for always but not completely.

Example:

I might be looking for Matcht in Matchthisstring so I match but not the entire string.

String 1 might come before or after string 2 and it might start with an uppercase or lower case letter.

Example:

I might be looking for actually but have Actually.

But it together and I have things like Matchthisstring.Actually or actually.Matchthisstring or Matchthisstring.someotherjunkIdon'tcareabout.actually any other combinations like that.

I'm having problems using the two search strings together and getting the reggae to work.

Here's an example of some code that works:

```
 my @matches;
   while (<$in_fh>) {
     #push @matches, $_ if / \Q$wanted\E .* \Q$prefix\E /x;
     #push @matches, $_ if / \Q^*(.*)$wanted\s*(.*)\E .* \Q^*(.*)$prefix\s*(.*)\E /x;
     push @matches, $_ if / \Q$wanted\E /x;
   }
```

what I really want to work is one of the other options that's commented out.  I don't think I'm joining the two searches into one string together properly.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please provide some examples with expected output

Comment: What's in `$wanted`?  What's in `$prefix`?

Comment: I'm up for learning and not asking for a hand out.  I'm writing scripts and asking for help when I get stuck, not for people to write scripts for me.  Any good books or online resources you think I should use so I can get better?  I'm just trying to get better and learn.

Comment: @tialin: As I said, you have ignored all the advice have given and seem to be patching in sections of code in the hope that something may work. No one will want to offer more advice just to be ignored. It is very simple to search for Perl tutorials on the internet. If you read them and correctly answer several Perl questions on Stack Overflow every day for a year or two then you could call yourself proficient.

Comment: @Borodin Well this is way better than the previous question because it's reasonably focused.  Not necessarily focused on the right aspect of the problem, but still -- better.  Thanks for the pointer to the earlier thread.

Comment: @tripleee:  Take a look at the history of that previous question. It started out looking maybe okay. You'll have gathered that I'm pretty angry about this guy's questions. He appears to have no problem-solving skills at all, never mind the HTML and Java that he professes to know well. And he's helping a friend! Sheesh.

Comment: @Borodin I think you have made your point, and while I personally sympathize, I think the sane and professional way to handle this is to cool down, downvote, and move on.  On its own, this particular question is not (yet? :-) deserving of massive flame.

Comment: I took all of your advise, & didn't ignore.  I took about 20 mins. to post 3 different scripts I'm running prior to the one that I'm working on in the last post as you asked & included all raw data after you flamed me last.  After that you didn't respond I started a new question figuring you had moved on.The problem that I still have is that this regex "push @matches, $_ if / \Q$prefix\E .* \Q$wanted\E /x;" is still not pulling this line from my file, "https://www.lghfoundation.com/donate/john-hansen.aspx" where $wanted="/donate" and $prefix="lghfound" & I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @tripleee: Still think I've made my point?! You're right though, it's early morning and I'm tired and should sleep. I hope this gets fixed fruitfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want

```
push @matches, $_ if /\Q$wanted\E/ and /\Q$prefix\E/;
```

Demo:

```
$ perl -ne 'use strict; use warnings; use vars qw($wanted $prefix @matches);
>    BEGIN {  $wanted = "/donate"; $prefix = "lghfound"; }
>    push @matches, $_ if /\Q$wanted\E/ and /\Q$prefix\E/; print @matches' <<'HERE'
> http://www.google.com/donate
> http://lghfoundation.com/pages/donate.html
> http://example.com
> HERE
http://lghfoundation.com/pages/donate.html
http://lghfoundation.com/pages/donate.html
```

Comment: The problem that I still have is that this regex "push (at)matches, $_ if / \Q$prefix\E .* \Q$wanted\E /x;" is still not pulling this line from my file, "lghfoundation.com/donate/john-hansen.aspx"; where $wanted="/donate" and $prefix="lghfound" & I'm trying to figure out why. The regex "push @matches, $_ if /\Q$wanted\E/ and /\Q$prefix\E/;" doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Works for me.  Updated with example.